# jQuery ui sortable() not easy to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have multiple forms and I added sortable function to them

And when the user drag the form they all get small height so the user can see all of them

The problem I'm facing that when dragging the form the placeholder not showing easily for the position

This my js code

```
jQuery('#test').sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    items: '> div.foo',
    distance: 5,
    handle: '.move',
    cancel: '',
    start: function () {
        jQuery(this).children('.foo').addClass('goooo');
    },
    stop: function () {
        jQuery(this).children('.foo').removeClass('goooo');
    }
});
```

And this the code in action to trying yourself

http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/jzr2g/

I'm open to any alternate, most important thing is all form get small height
If is there is a way to make the placeholder show always It will be grate

Comment: how about external control to allow sort?  http://jsfiddle.net/jzr2g/1/

Comment: @charlietfl Thanx, but the only problem with this solution is the forms not look alike and there is forms not have text input at the first just radio and when you change the height for all of them you can't know what is where

Comment: will have same problem either way...use a heading for each form, hide everything but the heading for sorting

Comment: @charlietfl can I make the placeholder show repeatedly ready for drop?

Comment: don't understand question

Comment: Why, drag and drop? create a button for up or down, it would be easyer to use

Comment: @charlietfl I meant like this http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/jzr2g/2/